# How to enable text wrapping in gvim?

Tags: vim

I am using gvim. The long text lines don't wrap around whenever I resize my gvim window. Same thing happens whenever I open a text file which has pretty long text in one line.

Is there any command I can set in .vimrc to enable this?

Answer (score 4):

If you want soft-wrapping, try:

```
:set wrap
```

Add it (without the colon) to your `~/.vimrc` to make that setting "stick" across sessions.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `:set wrap` suggested by others, I like to also use `:set linebreak`. When both are set, the soft wrapping only happens on whitespace. Set them together with `:set wrap linebreak`.

This is true with one caveat: if `'list'` is also set, `'linebreak'` has no effect.

To tell the difference between wrapped and unwrapped lines, I also like using the `'showbreak'` option. This gets set to a string to show in a different color at the beginning of every wrapped continuation of a line.

Answer (score 2):

To soft-wrap existing long lines, you want to set the `'wrap'` option.  For one buffer, just `:set wrap`.  If you want to turn it on for all files detected as 'text', put this line in your .vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType text setlocal wrap
```

To set the width (hard wrap) for text you enter, use the `textwidth` variable.  To set in your .vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78
```

This breaks down as: for all buffers of file type text, set locally the variable `textwidth` to 78.  I'm assuming you're using an 80-character-wide window.